# How many actions does a Bida need to use to sustain its Improved Grab on multiple creatures?

Tags: monsters, grapple, pathfinder-2e

A [Bida](https://2e.aonprd.com/Monsters.aspx?ID=440) has grabbed three people with its tail via its Eight Coils and [Improved Grab](https://2e.aonprd.com/MonsterAbilities.aspx?ID=27) ability. How many actions does it need to use to keep all three of those people grabbed? 1? 3? I'd guess it works like [Constrict](https://2e.aonprd.com/MonsterAbilities.aspx?ID=10) (one action for all of them), especially since it'd be impossible to grab 8 people otherwise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**One**

From the rules for [Grab](https://2e.aonprd.com/MonsterAbilities.aspx?ID=18) -

> Using Grab extends the duration of the monster's Grab until the end of its next turn for all creatures grabbed by it.

Comment: Would have helped if I read the Grab action too... *facepalm*